# How the eigen vector changed to identity matrix in kpca steps?

Tags: matlab, pca

```
[eigvec eigval] = eigs(K_center,[],neigs,'lm',opts);
disp('***********Eigen value(1)***************')
disp(eigval)
eig_val = eigval ~= 0;
disp('***********Eigen value(2)***************')
disp(eig_val)

 Output:

***********Eigen value(1)***************
    4.0001         0         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0         0    1.0000

***********Eigen value(2)***************
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

The eigen values returned are shown in Eigen value(1)...but after setting eigenvalues ~= 0 ...I get an identity matrix as shown in eigen value(2)..How has it changed to be an identity matrix and why ? I am refering

```
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27319-kernel-   pca/content/kernelpca_tutorial.m
```

Any help appreciated..Thanx in advance..

Comment: You compare `eigval` to `0`, so the result will be a logical matrix with `1` for all non-zero elements and `0` for all elements which are zero. This is exactly what is happening. What is the result you want?

Comment: Thank uu!!...i thought ~= meant not equal to in matlab.!..Also,K(row,col) = exp(-temp); % sigma = 1 is the guassian kernel used and i dont get to see the divided by 2 part in the equation... @ hbaderts